# Noun / Adjective / Etc Word Lists or Dictionaries (Common Words)

Tags: dictionary, cpu-word

I am looking for dictionaries that are split up by parts of speech and are preferably more common words.

I am trying to generate random band names for fun.

I found a set of dictionaries [HERE](http://www.ashley-bovan.co.uk/words/wordlists.html) which was compiled from the **MOBY Word Lists** and the **UK Advanced Cryptics Dictionary**, however, when I generate random band names I get stuff like this:

```
bandName = "Nummulite Repercussions"
bandName = "Lemures DebasementsEarphones"
```

which is obviously dumb.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists.html has some decent short lists but they are hard to get in a usable form.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small yet sufficient and extensible PHP [library](https://github.com/Kolyunya/wiktionary-parser) for parsing the wiktionary.org categories. You can parse lists of nouns, adjectives, e.t.c. All you need to do is to select a desired category.

The repository has noun dictionaries in `samples` directory as an example of its work.