# Getting a Large List of Nouns (or Adjectives) in Python with NLTK; or Python Mad Libs

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439555/noun-adjective-etc-word-lists-or-dictionaries-common-words), I am interested in getting a large list of words by part of speech (a long list of nouns; a list of adjectives) to be used programmatically elsewhere. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108757/get-list-of-nouns-adjectives-from-wordnet) has a solution using the WordNet database (in SQL) format.

Is there a way to get at such list using the corpora/tools built into the Python NLTK. I could take a large bunch of text, parse it and then store the nouns and adjectives. But given the dictionaries and other tools built in, is there a smarter way to simply extract the words that are already present in the NLTK datasets, encoded as nouns/adjectives (whatever)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's worth noting that Wordnet is actually one of the corpora included in the NLTK downloader by default. So you could conceivably just use the solution you already found without having to reinvent any wheels.

For instance, you could just do something like this to get all noun synsets:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

for synset in list(wn.all_synsets('n')):
    print synset

# Or, equivalently
for synset in list(wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN)):
    print synset
```

That example will give you every noun that you want and it will even group them into their synsets so you can try to be sure that they're being used in the correct context.

If you want to get them all into a list you can do something like the following (though this will vary quite a bit based on how you want to use the words and synsets):

```
all_nouns = []
for synset in wn.all_synsets('n'):
    all_nouns.extend(synset.lemma_names())
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
all_nouns = [word for synset in wn.all_synsets('n') for word in synset.lemma_names()]
```

Comment: Excellent. I'll try this. I knew wordnet was part of NLTK, but I didn't grok the api sufficiently. Thanks.

Comment: Should this be `...list(wn.all_synsets(wn.NOUN))...`? wn.NOUN is a constant set to 'n', but it is more readable

Comment: @Oxinabox arguably more readable, I'll include the note though, thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: list(wn.wordnet.all_synsets(wn.wordnet.NOUN)) for python 3, 'ADJ', 'ADJ_SAT', 'ADV',  'VERB' are also possible

Comment: The question requested a word not a synset

Comment: @user2585501 The question asked for a long lists of words. Not a single word.

Comment: @slater-victoroff synsets contain lemmas, which is useful in some (if not most) contexts.

Comment: @user2585501 I've updated it to be a bit clearer in case folks aren't familiar with the fact that you can directly access the words in a synset.

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution.
I used the lines 
``from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn`` and 
``all_nouns = [word for synset in wn.all_synsets('n') for word in synset.lemma_names()]``

the length of list is 146347 just in case another person reads this

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Moby Parts of Speech Project](http://archive.org/details/mobypartofspeech03203gut) data. Don't be fixated on using only what is directly in NLTK by default. It would be little work to download the files for this and pretty easy to parse them with NLTK once loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar question earlier this week (can't find the link), but like I said then, I don't think maintaining a list of nouns/adjectives/whatever is a great idea. This is primarily because the same word can have different parts of speech, depending on the context.

However, if you are still dead set on using these lists, then here's how I would do it (I don't have a working NLTK install on this machine, but I remember the basics):

```
nouns = set()
for sentence in my_corpus.sents():
    # each sentence is either a list of words or a list of (word, POS tag) tuples
    for word, pos in nltk.pos_tag(sentence): # remove the call to nltk.pos_tag if `sentence` is a list of tuples as described above

        if pos in ['NN', "NNP"]: # feel free to add any other noun tags
            nouns.add(word)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Oof, why pos_tag a different corpus when you could just have use a pre-built one? I feel like this would take an extremely long time for a large corpus.

Comment: Depending on the use, the fact that the same "word" (let's say "string" to not get the linguists angry) may exist as multiple parts of speech is no problem. If you're writing a Mad-Lib completer, the fact that scratch is both noun and verb, is no problem, right?

I do like that this solution doesn't require downloading/parsing another file.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: I didn't mean to suggest that the OP should pos tag a new corpus. Rather, I meant to convey that one of the corpora that comes with NLTK should be tagged. If I remember correctly, if the corpus is already tagged, `pos_tag` does not perform any new tagging, but just returns the already tagged data

Comment: Ooh, I see. My mistake, that makes much more sense.