# How might I generate a word list of irregular plural noun programmatically?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I would like to programmatically generate a list of the most common irregular plural nouns. I know that I can get a [list of all nouns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753182/getting-a-large-list-of-nouns-or-adjectives-in-python-with-nltk-or-python-mad). But is there a way to get a list of irregular plural nouns, e.g. radii, children, etc?

Would I take the list of all nouns, and then check if the plural (NNS)and the singular (NN) do not follow the "ends with s" rule?

Comment: You have to show some code and efforts You have made towards this question

Comment: possibly that is a solution, that is more of a phonetics question because programmaticaly it should not be that complicated. and You probably have to use list of all nouns and check them individually (using a program) but as I mentioned You havee to look ap rules as to what makes a noun irregular